# How to obtain only ALL Undocumented Stored Procs in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I write

```
SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE ([type] = 'P');
```

I will get all the SQL Stored Procedure. But how to obtain only the Undocumented ones?

Thanks

Comment: can you tell us what you mean by undocumented

Comment: e.g. XP_FileExist,SP_MSForEachDb etc.

Comment: I only want to list the undocumented stored procs e.g. sp_activedirectory is a documented one while SP_MSForEachDb  is not so.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to query this list, but you can find it here

[**List of Undocumented Stored Procedures in SQL Server**](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/04/list-of-undocumented-stored-procedures.html)